# How to obtain mass attenuation coefficients of a compound given mass attenuation coefficients of separate elements?

Tags: radiometry

Given a table of MACs for each element, like [this one](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/tab3.html), is it possible to obtain a MAC for a chemical compound or solution? If so, how do I obtain one?

Comment: In all generality, there is no simple way. You could make an approximation and assume that the compound absorbs like a linear combination of the elements at their respective densities. But, in general there could be subtle effects due to bonding, etc.

Comment: @hft what's the non-simple way? Can I simulate it?

Comment: The non-simple way is: Solve the Schrödinger equation for the compound and calculate the absorption spectrum using Fermi's Golden Rule.